# parse/backbone collection get and getByCid not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm doing some changes in the models of a `Parse.Collection`, and at the end of the changes, I'm having trouble finding the right model of the Collection.

I have a model called `thisDrive.attributes.clusterStart`. It does not matter if this model have been fetched or not. I can access it's `id` and `cid` property. The `id` = `mzy36FdGT8`

The collection where this models are contained is called `clustersCollection`.

The following line returns `undefined`:

```
clustersCollection.get(thisDrive.attributes.clusterStart.id);
```

I'm sure the model with `id` = `mzy36FdGT8` exist in `clustersCollection` because

```
clustersCollection.models[0].id
```

returns

```
"mzy36FdGT8"
```

[image]

The `cid`s of the model I have in `thisDrive.attributes.clusterStart` is different than the `cid` of the first model in the collection.

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `clustersCollection` fetched when you trying to get the `model` by `id`?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan yes, I'm completely sure,since I work with promises and this is part of a huge script. the fetching occurs at the very beginning and It only moves along as soon as it's ready. As you can see in the picture, I can try this on the console and I get the same error, no matter how long I wait.

Comment: The get method relies on an internal object `_byId` being populated and mapping each id/cid with the model: `return this._byId[obj] || this._byId[obj.id] || this._byId[obj.cid];`. This internal object `_byId` is internally handled when fetching/adding/removing models. What changes are you doing in the parse method?

Comment: First, I fetch the collection. then,I will add, modify and/or delete some models from the collection. The adding is done with `clustersCollection.add(thisNewCluster);`, modifications are done with the method `set` and the removals with the method remove.... is there a way to trigger a recalculation of the `_byId` object?